# How to sum all possible products of N digits from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some dataframes which contain numbers. And I want to sum all possible products of N (N is integer >=2) columns for each row.  How can I do it? Thank you for helping :)

```
#For example I want to sum all possible products of 3 digitals from 4 cols
df <- data.frame(rep(4:6,time=2),rep(6:4,time=2),rep(6:8,2),rep(8:10,2))
colnames(df) <- c(1,2,3,4)

# ideal result for first row is 4*6*6+4*6*8+6*6*8+4*6*8=816

  1 2 3  4 sumproduct3
1 4 6 6  8    816  #4*6*6+4*6*8+4*6*8+6*6*8
2 5 5 7  9    1030 #5*5*7+5*5*9+5*7*9+5*7*9
3 6 4 8 10    1232 #4*8*10+6*8*10+6*4*10+6*4*8
4 4 6 6  8    ...
5 5 5 7  9    ...
6 6 4 8 10    ...
#The idea I have got so far is using combn(4,3) to generate all permutation 
#but I dont know how to aply them in to df yet
> combn(4,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    3    3
[3,]    3    4    4    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write a function that will produce the sum of all possible products given a specified `n` for one vector:

```
FUN <- function(x, n){
  m <- matrix(as.numeric(combn(x, n)), nrow = n)
  s <- sum(apply(m, 2, prod))
}
```

Now we `apply()` this function to all rows of the dataframe `df`, specifying `n` as 3:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) FUN(x, 3))
```

Result:

```
[1]  816 1030 1232  816 1030 1232
```

This can be appended to the dataframe:

```
df$sum <- apply(df, 1, function(x) FUN(x, 3))
df

  1 2 3  4  sum
1 4 6 6  8  816
2 5 5 7  9 1030
3 6 4 8 10 1232
4 4 6 6  8  816
5 5 5 7  9 1030
6 6 4 8 10 1232
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but I try your FUN and get the result like this > apply(df, 1, function(x) FUN(x, 3))
[1] 77400 87442 97992

Comment: I've just made a slight change, I forgot to define the `nrow` as variable `n` within the function.

Comment: Are those values for the dataset you provided above?

Comment: Yeah, I just clean the environment and try it again. The results keep the same like this > apply(df, 1, function(x) FUN(x, 3))
[1] 77400 87442 97992

Comment: Well, for me it works with the `df` you gave in your question.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I have found my problem. It works perfectly. Thank you ~~

Comment: Could you tell me what is function prob? I dont really understand how it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173381/discussion-between-codezy-and-lap).